# Windows embedded CE 6.0 USB printer driver

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I am going to write USB printer driver for Windows Embedded CE 6.0. But I dont know from where to start. Now I installed VS2005, patches of WinCE6.0, VS2005 team suite SP1, Platform Builder SP1, R2,R3.

Tell me how to start to write the driver, whether from VS 2005. In which application I am going to write the driver application. How to use platform Builder, how PB is helpful for me to write the USB driver.

I have Win CE 6.0 device is with me. Plz help me .

pcl.dll is not working for this device. plz tell me how to write driver, steps for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to plug a printer into your CE device, start with the source found on your PC at:

`C:\WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\DRIVERS\USB\CLASS\PRINTER`

If you want your CE device to act as a printer, start with the source found on your PC at:

`C:\WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\DRIVERS\USBFN\CLASS\UFNPRN`

[Clone the code to your BSP](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/07/02/platform-builder-clone-public-code.aspx) (do *not* modify the code in the locations above), make the modifications and then do the build/sysgen/makeimg as necessary.  Iterate until you have what you want.